# In what transaction can we maintain the print programs, routines and Forms, to be printed in transaction QM02?

Tags: printing, transactions, settings, abap, sap-erp

I need to modify a standard form, and to do this, I'm copying it to a Z* form, and I'd like to know where my print program and SapScript form is being assigned to the workflow.

Anyway, since a lot of transactions seem to work like this: T1 - prints, T2-sets the printing options, is there any pattern that I could use to find the T2 type transactions?

Of course, in my case, It's enough if I get the transactions where the settings for QM02 are specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output control (print programs) are usually configured in the IMG.

Run transaction SPRO

Search for Output control or Print control.  (In this case Output control did not result in anything useful, but Print control gave me the following:)

[image]

[image]

Assign Shop Papers to Notification Type tells you which Shop Paper (4CHAR code) you care about, Define Shop Papers has the ABAP Form and print Program

[image]

I used to be able to use table TNAPR to find the other half of the print program/print form combination, but as Sapscript has become less used that table seems to be less useful.

Answer (score 2):

if you can't find the related print program in customizing than trace or debug how the function 'OPEN_FORM' is called in your case